# CSS-styling only applies to Home View in ASP.NET Core 5.0 MVC-app

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I have created an MVC app in which the file _Layout.cshtml applies to all views, but the styles do only apply to the home view. So for instance I have provided two screenshots of my web app. One of the **home view**, in which clearly the CSS stylesheet is applied, but in contrast, the **create view** has the same Layout but without the CSS styles. I have tried searching for a solution for this issue but could unfortunately not find anything that would resolve it. I am running ASP.NET core 5.0 on Mac OS.

This is a screenshot of the Home View:

[image]

This is a screenshot of my Create-page

[image]

_Layout.cshtml

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">


<head>

    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
    <meta name="description" content="">
    <meta name="author" content="">

    <title>SB Admin 2 - Blank</title>

    <!-- Custom fonts for this template-->




    <link href="vendor/fontawesome-free/css/all.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Nunito:200,200i,300,300i,400,400i,600,600i,700,700i,800,800i,900,900i"
          rel="stylesheet">

    <!-- Custom styles for this template-->

    <link href="css/sb-admin-2.min.css" rel="stylesheet">

  

</head>

<body id="page-top">

    <!-- Page Wrapper -->
    <div id="wrapper">

        <!-- Sidebar -->
        <ul class="navbar-nav bg-gradient-primary sidebar sidebar-dark accordion" id="accordionSidebar">

            <!-- Sidebar - Brand -->
            <a class="sidebar-brand d-flex align-items-center justify-content-center" href="index.html">
                <div class="sidebar-brand-icon rotate-n-15">
                    <i class="fas fa-laugh-wink"></i>
                </div>
                <div class="sidebar-brand-text mx-3">SB Admin <sup>2</sup></div>
            </a>

            <!-- Divider -->
            <hr class="sidebar-divider my-0">

            <!-- Nav Item - Dashboard -->
            <li class="nav-item">
                <a class="nav-link" href="index.html">
                    <i class="fas fa-fw fa-tachometer-alt"></i>
                    <span>Dashboard</span>
                </a>
            </li>

            <!-- Divider -->
            <hr class="sidebar-divider">

            <!-- Heading -->
            <div class="sidebar-heading">
                Interface
            </div>






            <!-- Nav Item - Charts -->
            <li class="nav-item">
                <a class="nav-link" asp-area="" asp-controller="Home" asp-action="Index">

                    <span>Home</span>
                </a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
                <a class="nav-link" asp-area="" asp-controller="Home" asp-action="Privacy">

                    <span>Privacy</span>
                </a>
            </li>

            <!-- Nav Item - Tables -->
            <li class="nav-item">
                <a class="nav-link" href="tables.html">
                    <i class="fas fa-fw fa-table"></i>
                    <span>Tables</span>
                </a>
            </li>

            <!-- Divider -->
            <hr class="sidebar-divider d-none d-md-block">

            <!-- Sidebar Toggler (Sidebar) -->
            <div class="text-center d-none d-md-inline">
                <button class="rounded-circle border-0" id="sidebarToggle"></button>
            </div>

        </ul>
        <!-- End of Sidebar -->
        <!-- Content Wrapper -->
        <div id="content-wrapper" class="d-flex flex-column">

            <!-- Main Content -->
            <div id="content">

                <!-- Topbar -->
                <nav class="navbar navbar-expand navbar-light bg-white topbar mb-4 static-top shadow">

                    <!-- Sidebar Toggle (Topbar) -->
                    <button id="sidebarToggleTop" class="btn btn-link d-md-none rounded-circle mr-3">
                        <i class="fa fa-bars"></i>
                    </button>

                    <!-- Topbar Search -->
                    <form class="d-none d-sm-inline-block form-inline mr-auto ml-md-3 my-2 my-md-0 mw-100 navbar-search">
                        <div class="input-group">
                            <input type="text" class="form-control bg-light border-0 small" placeholder="Search for..."
                                   aria-label="Search" aria-describedby="basic-addon2">
                            <div class="input-group-append">
                                <button class="btn btn-primary" type="button">
                                    <i class="fas fa-search fa-sm"></i>
                                </button>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </form>

                    <!-- Topbar Navbar -->
                    <ul class="navbar-nav ml-auto">

                        <!-- Nav Item - Search Dropdown (Visible Only XS) -->
                        <li class="nav-item dropdown no-arrow d-sm-none">
                            <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#" id="searchDropdown" role="button"
                               data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
                                <i class="fas fa-search fa-fw"></i>
                            </a>
                            <!-- Dropdown - Messages -->
                            <div class="dropdown-menu dropdown-menu-right p-3 shadow animated--grow-in"
                                 aria-labelledby="searchDropdown">
                                <form class="form-inline mr-auto w-100 navbar-search">
                                    <div class="input-group">
                                        <input type="text" class="form-control bg-light border-0 small"
                                               placeholder="Search for..." aria-label="Search"
                                               aria-describedby="basic-addon2">
                                        <div class="input-group-append">
                                            <button class="btn btn-primary" type="button">
                                                <i class="fas fa-search fa-sm"></i>
                                            </button>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </form>
                            </div>
                        </li>

                        <!-- Nav Item - Alerts -->
                        <li class="nav-item dropdown no-arrow mx-1">
                            <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#" id="alertsDropdown" role="button"
                               data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
                                <i class="fas fa-bell fa-fw"></i>
                                <!-- Counter - Alerts -->
                                <span class="badge badge-danger badge-counter">3+</span>
                            </a>
                            <!-- Dropdown - Alerts -->
                            <div class="dropdown-list dropdown-menu dropdown-menu-right shadow animated--grow-in"
                                 aria-labelledby="alertsDropdown">
                                <h6 class="dropdown-header">
                                    Alerts Center
                                </h6>
                                <a class="dropdown-item d-flex align-items-center" href="#">
                                    <div class="mr-3">
                                        <div class="icon-circle bg-primary">
                                            <i class="fas fa-file-alt text-white"></i>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                    <div>
                                        <div class="small text-gray-500">December 12, 2019</div>
                                        <span class="font-weight-bold">A new monthly report is ready to download!</span>
                                    </div>
                                </a>
                                <a class="dropdown-item d-flex align-items-center" href="#">
                                    <div class="mr-3">
                                        <div class="icon-circle bg-success">
                                            <i class="fas fa-donate text-white"></i>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                    <div>
                                        <div class="small text-gray-500">December 7, 2019</div>
                                        $290.29 has been deposited into your account!
                                    </div>
                                </a>
                                <a class="dropdown-item d-flex align-items-center" href="#">
                                    <div class="mr-3">
                                        <div class="icon-circle bg-warning">
                                            <i class="fas fa-exclamation-triangle text-white"></i>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                    <div>
                                        <div class="small text-gray-500">December 2, 2019</div>
                                        Spending Alert: We've noticed unusually high spending for your account.
                                    </div>
                                </a>
                                <a class="dropdown-item text-center small text-gray-500" href="#">Show All Alerts</a>
                            </div>
                        </li>

                        <!-- Nav Item - Messages -->
                        <li class="nav-item dropdown no-arrow mx-1">
                            <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#" id="messagesDropdown" role="button"
                               data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
                                <i class="fas fa-envelope fa-fw"></i>
                                <!-- Counter - Messages -->
                                <span class="badge badge-danger badge-counter">7</span>
                            </a>
                            <!-- Dropdown - Messages -->
                            <div class="dropdown-list dropdown-menu dropdown-menu-right shadow animated--grow-in"
                                 aria-labelledby="messagesDropdown">
                                <h6 class="dropdown-header">
                                    Message Center
                                </h6>
                                <a class="dropdown-item d-flex align-items-center" href="#">
                                    <div class="dropdown-list-image mr-3">
                                        <img class="rounded-circle" src="img/undraw_profile_1.svg"
                                             alt="...">
                                        <div class="status-indicator bg-success"></div>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="font-weight-bold">
                                        <div class="text-truncate">
                                            Hi there! I am wondering if you can help me with a
                                            problem I've been having.
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="small text-gray-500">Emily Fowler · 58m</div>
                                    </div>
                                </a>
                                <a class="dropdown-item d-flex align-items-center" href="#">
                                    <div class="dropdown-list-image mr-3">
                                        <img class="rounded-circle" src="img/undraw_profile_2.svg"
                                             alt="...">
                                        <div class="status-indicator"></div>
                                    </div>
                                    <div>
                                        <div class="text-truncate">
                                            I have the photos that you ordered last month, how
                                            would you like them sent to you?
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="small text-gray-500">Jae Chun · 1d</div>
                                    </div>
                                </a>
                                <a class="dropdown-item d-flex align-items-center" href="#">
                                    <div class="dropdown-list-image mr-3">
                                        <img class="rounded-circle" src="img/undraw_profile_3.svg"
                                             alt="...">
                                        <div class="status-indicator bg-warning"></div>
                                    </div>
                                    <div>
                                        <div class="text-truncate">
                                            Last month's report looks great, I am very happy with
                                            the progress so far, keep up the good work!
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="small text-gray-500">Morgan Alvarez · 2d</div>
                                    </div>
                                </a>
                                <a class="dropdown-item d-flex align-items-center" href="#">
                                    <div class="dropdown-list-image mr-3">
                                        <img class="rounded-circle" src="https://source.unsplash.com/Mv9hjnEUHR4/60x60"
                                             alt="...">
                                        <div class="status-indicator bg-success"></div>
                                    </div>
                                    <div>
                                        <div class="text-truncate">
                                            Am I a good boy? The reason I ask is because someone
                                            told me that people say this to all dogs, even if they aren't good...
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="small text-gray-500">Chicken the Dog · 2w</div>
                                    </div>
                                </a>
                                <a class="dropdown-item text-center small text-gray-500" href="#">Read More Messages</a>
                            </div>
                        </li>

                        <div class="topbar-divider d-none d-sm-block"></div>

                        <!-- Nav Item - User Information -->
                        <li class="nav-item dropdown no-arrow">
                            <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#" id="userDropdown" role="button"
                               data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
                                <span class="mr-2 d-none d-lg-inline text-gray-600 small">Douglas McGee</span>
                                <img class="img-profile rounded-circle"
                                     src="img/undraw_profile.svg">
                            </a>
                            <!-- Dropdown - User Information -->
                            <div class="dropdown-menu dropdown-menu-right shadow animated--grow-in"
                                 aria-labelledby="userDropdown">
                                <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">
                                    <i class="fas fa-user fa-sm fa-fw mr-2 text-gray-400"></i>
                                    Profile
                                </a>
                                <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">
                                    <i class="fas fa-cogs fa-sm fa-fw mr-2 text-gray-400"></i>
                                    Settings
                                </a>
                                <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">
                                    <i class="fas fa-list fa-sm fa-fw mr-2 text-gray-400"></i>
                                    Activity Log
                                </a>
                                <div class="dropdown-divider"></div>
                                <a class="dropdown-item" href="#" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#logoutModal">
                                    <i class="fas fa-sign-out-alt fa-sm fa-fw mr-2 text-gray-400"></i>
                                    Logout
                                </a>
                            </div>
                        </li>

                    </ul>

                </nav>
                <!-- End of Topbar -->
                <!-- Begin Page Content -->
                <div class="container-fluid">

                    <!-- Page Heading -->

                    <main role="main" class="pb-3">
                        <div class="container-fluid">
                            @RenderBody()

                        </div>

                    </main>

                </div>
                <!-- /.container-fluid -->

            </div>
            <!-- End of Main Content -->
            <!-- Footer -->
            <footer class="sticky-footer bg-white">
                <div class="container my-auto">
                    <div class="copyright text-center my-auto">
                        <span>Copyright &copy; Your Website 2020</span>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </footer>
            <!-- End of Footer -->

        </div>
        <!-- End of Content Wrapper -->

    </div>
    <!-- End of Page Wrapper -->
    <!-- Scroll to Top Button-->
    <a class="scroll-to-top rounded" href="#page-top">
        <i class="fas fa-angle-up"></i>
    </a>

    <!-- Logout Modal-->
    <div class="modal fade" id="logoutModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel"
         aria-hidden="true">
        <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
            <div class="modal-content">
                <div class="modal-header">
                    <h5 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLabel">Ready to Leave?</h5>
                    <button class="close" type="button" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
                        <span aria-hidden="true">×</span>
                    </button>
                </div>
                <div class="modal-body">Select "Logout" below if you are ready to end your current session.</div>
                <div class="modal-footer">
                    <button class="btn btn-secondary" type="button" data-dismiss="modal">Cancel</button>
                    <a class="btn btn-primary" href="login.html">Logout</a>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <!-- Bootstrap core JavaScript-->
    <script src="wwwroot/vendor/jquery/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="wwwroot/vendor/bootstrap/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>

    <!-- Core plugin JavaScript-->
    <script src="wwwroot/vendor/jquery-easing/jquery.easing.min.js"></script>

    <!-- Custom scripts for all pages-->
    <script src="wwwroot/vendor/js/sb-admin-2.min.js"></script>
    @await RenderSectionAsync("Scripts", required: false)


</body>

</html>
```

Create.cshtml

```html
@model IssueTracker.Models.Issue

@{ ViewData["Title"] = "Create"; }

<h1>Create</h1>

<h4>Issue</h4>
<hr />
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-4">
        <form asp-action="Create">
            <div asp-validation-summary="ModelOnly" class="text-danger"></div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label asp-for="Title" class="control-label"></label>
                <input asp-for="Title" class="form-control" />
                <span asp-validation-for="Title" class="text-danger"></span>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label asp-for="Submitter" class="control-label"></label>
                <input asp-for="Submitter" class="form-control" />
                <span asp-validation-for="Submitter" class="text-danger"></span>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label asp-for="AssignedDev" class="control-label"></label>
                <input asp-for="AssignedDev" class="form-control" />
                <span asp-validation-for="AssignedDev" class="text-danger"></span>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label asp-for="Status" class="control-label"></label>
                <input asp-for="Status" class="form-control" />
                <span asp-validation-for="Status" class="text-danger"></span>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label asp-for="Created" class="control-label"></label>
                <input asp-for="Created" class="form-control" />
                <span asp-validation-for="Created" class="text-danger"></span>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label asp-for="Project" class="control-label"></label>
                <input asp-for="Project" class="form-control" />
                <span asp-validation-for="Project" class="text-danger"></span>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label asp-for="Priority" class="control-label"></label>
                <input asp-for="Priority" class="form-control" />
                <span asp-validation-for="Priority" class="text-danger"></span>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label asp-for="Type" class="control-label"></label>
                <input asp-for="Type" class="form-control" />
                <span asp-validation-for="Type" class="text-danger"></span>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <input type="submit" value="Create" class="btn btn-primary" />
            </div>
        </form>
    </div>
</div>

<div>
    <a asp-action="Index">Back to List</a>
</div>

@section Scripts {
    @{await Html.RenderPartialAsync("_ValidationScriptsPartial");}
}
```

_ViewStart.cshtml

```html
@{ Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml"; }
```

Screenshot of my Project directory

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this in _ViewStart.cshtml

```
@{
    Layout = "_Layout";
}
```

and check if in _ViewImports.cshtml you have something like:

```
@using IssueTracker
@using IssueTracker.Models
@addTagHelper *, Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.TagHelpers
```

and you have all the CSS with a *file* related path instead of a *project* related path :

```
    <link href="vendor/fontawesome-free/css/all.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
```

should be

```
<link href="~/css/vendor/fontawesome-free/css/all.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
```

Comment: I tried it, but the issue persists. Still no CSS styles applied on the views other than the home view.

Comment: I tested the second portion of your answer and it still is not resolved.

Comment: Look at my latest addition